# How to add class to embedded Paragraphs field-items?

Tags: 7, theming, paragraphs

I have a Paragraph field embedded on a node type. The Paragraph field type allows for many different Paragraph Bundles to be inserted into the node.

My mark up currently displays as (Drupal 7 zen Theme):

```
<div class="paragraphs-items paragraphs-items-field-paragraphs paragraphs-items-field-paragraphs-full paragraphs-items-full">
```

How can I add a class after each field-paragraphs? I would want to do this so that each Bundle has it's own class.

I've tried the following in my themes template file but it adds a class around the entire field and not on each Bundle:

```
    function mytheme_preprocess_paragraphs_items(&$vars, $hook) {

  // This will remove all the current classes
  $vars['classes_array'] = "";

  // You can now add the classes you want in this array
  $vars['classes_array'][] = "myclass";
}
```

[image: Paragraphs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Drupal 7

You *should* be able to copy this function into your `template.php` file of your theme:

```
/**
 * Process variables for paragraphs-items.tpl.php
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraphs_items(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['view_mode'] = $variables['element']['#view_mode'];
  $variables['field_name'] = $variables['element']['#field_name'];

  $variables['content'] = $variables['element']['#children'];

  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('paragraphs-items-' . $variables['element']['#field_name']);
  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('paragraphs-items-' . $variables['element']['#field_name'] . '-' . $variables['view_mode']);
  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('paragraphs-items-' . $variables['view_mode']);

  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'paragraphs_items__' . $variables['element']['#field_name'];
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'paragraphs_items__' . $variables['element']['#field_name'] . '__' . $variables['view_mode'];

  // your code here 
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'your-class';
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'your-other-class';
}
```

You should also be able to do this for individual item:

```
/**
 * Process variables for paragraphs-item.tpl.php
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraphs_item(&$variables, $hook) {
  // your code here 
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'your-class';
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'your-other-class';
}
```

After adding this function, clear the cache so it is registered. You can then check if either one are being called by adding a breakpoint or `print 'called'; exit;` if you do not have something like XDebug installed.

Note how the second function is `paragraphs_item` and not `paragraphs_items`. Both of these are defined as theme hooks in paragraphs.module.

You can even do this as well:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_entity().
 * @param $variables
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_entity(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['entity_type'] == 'paragraphs_item' && $variables['elements']['#bundle'] == 'your_bundle') {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'your-class';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's for Drupal 7!

Comment: Thanks Keven, the code for each paragraphs-item is working. But I want to add it to the bundle (so that <div class="field-paragraphs"> has my-class appended to it. Do I replace #field-name in the first snippet with my bundle name?

Comment: No, that is for constructing dynamic template suggestions via `theme_hook_suggestions`. Which are you trying to alter, the paragraphs output, or the field that outputs the paragraphs?

Comment: The field output. They all are combined under under one wrapper at the moment and I need to target certain fields.

Comment: I've added a image for clarity

Comment: @Kevin It is possible to add classes to individual fields or specify html elements to individual fields of paragraphs bundle items?